# ASP.net CheckboxList Inserting to DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have a page with several CheckBoxList controls with 4 checkboxes in each of them and I'm trying to run an Insert statement for each of the checkboxes that are checked in the CheckBoxList controls after user hits on the Submit button. Any guide so as to how i can do this? Using OLEDB.

Comment: Please be specific, Try it yourself first then if any error occurs post that error with question on SO.

Comment: I understand that the CheckBoxList control doesn't allow to determine if an individual checkbox is checked, or am i wrong?

Comment: Yes it does. You need to iterate over Items property of CheckBoxList and test Selected property of each Item.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek do you have a sample code i can adhere to?

Comment: You can find sample here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.items.aspx (it creates a text message with selected item and you want to do something in database, but I believe doing something in database in beyond the scope of your question :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through them like this:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                // if item is checked do something
            }
        }
```